# How nopCommerce-API access from Fiddler or mobile app

Tags: .net, api, nopcommerce, nopcommerce-4.1

As a new to the nopCommerce, stuck in one issue. Need a nopCommerce API, use this you can create a product, retrieve a product, update a product or delete a product with out associated with your nopCommerce website.

API deploy separately not with nopCommerce website both have same Database and functionalities, suppose any mobile app or third party client tool like **Fiddler** can  access those functionality via API.

Note: my NopCommerce version is 4.10

Comment: Question is unclear! is your question regarding *how to deployed API separately?* or  *How to consume them?*. Generally, effortless approach is to create a plugin and use it with your website, it's easy to use as all the libraries and services are available with the same project. Once you deployed your project, you can simply consume apis by use of routing with client tools like Filddler or postman.

Comment: @Div thanks for your reply, i am new in nopCommerce, sorry for basic type question. After successfully implement nopCommerce website need to implement API in nop-commerce because i need api service for my mobile application which is not in nopCommerce platform. Need some mechanism or process for API implement in nopCommerce. For client access need to deploy those API separately not with website.

Comment: One question here is why do you want to make it separately, not with website?

Comment: @Div, please show some guideline/information it will be great help for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on comment, what you are trying to do is to create an API of your website and consume it from other platform(s). This is basic scenario where a single DB is being used from both the ends. Generally, in a simple MVC project, you can create an API project in solution where BAL and DAL are the same for web as well as API. Your

[image]

If you look around the nopCommerce, it's really simple to create an API. As nopCommerce is plugable architecture, you would need to develop a plugin(or have to use already developed by vendor [API Plugin](https://www.nopcommerce.com/p/2464/api-plugin.aspx) if required version available)

However, to make separate API you would need to use existing DLLs on APIs are depended on. Make sure to give reference of same DLLs that build by web project.